# Does family 'ocat' work with gamm4 in R?

Tags: mgcv, gamm4

I am trying to fit a GAMM to ordered categorical data using `gamm4` in R. In the help file for `gamm4`, it says the argument 'family' is "A `family` as used in a call to `glm` or `gam`." That being the case, I try to use family `ocat` from the `mgcv` package, which is designed for ordered categorical data. However, when I follow the example provided in the `ocat` help page (but adding random effects), I receive an error. Is this a bug, has `ocat` not properly been synced with `gamm4`, or is there some other issue I am missing?

Example:

```
library(mgcv)
## simulated some ordered categorical data...
set.seed(3);n<-400
dat <- gamSim(1,n=n)
dat$f <- dat$f - mean(dat$f)

alpha <- c(-Inf,-1,0,5,Inf)
R <- length(alpha)-1
y <- dat$f
u <- runif(n)
u <- dat$f + log(u/(1-u)) 
for (i in 1:R) {
  y[u > alpha[i]&u <= alpha[i+1]] <- i
}
dat$y <- y

## plot the data...
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
with(dat,plot(x0,y));with(dat,plot(x1,y))
with(dat,plot(x2,y));with(dat,plot(x3,y))

## fit ocat model to data...
b <- gam(y~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3),family=ocat(R=R),data=dat)
b
plot(b,pages=1)
gam.check(b)
summary(b)

##################################################
library(gamm4)

## add in some random effects and use gamm4
dat$f3 <- sample(1:40,400,T)
b2 <- gamm4(y~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3),random = ~ (1|f3),family = ocat(R=R),data = dat)
```

Comment: I think you would be better on an R-site or e-mailing the maintainer of the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `ocat` doesn't work with `gamm4()`. From `?family.mgcv`

> As well as the standard families documented in `family` (see also
>        `glm`) which can be used with functions `gam`, `bam` and `gamm`,
>        `mgcv` also supplies some extra families, most of which are
>         **currently only usable with `gam`, although some can also be used
>         with `bam`**...

(emphasis added). We need to take this literally.

I believe bits of the documentation have gotten out of sync — you can only use the families that `lmer` or `glmer` understand in `gamm4()`.